# Lua download POST request

Tags: lua, http-post

I working with Corona (Lua based)
and like to create a server that can store data that comes posted by a ordinary browser.

I am at the Point where I get the "POST" sequence and now would just need to store the incoming data.

some problems. After the Post I do not just get the file, first are coming several
headers and a "content-type" with a boundary= Info like "----WebKitFormBoundary1AA ..."

For now I try to analyze each single Line I get for the first beginning of that boundary sequence and the second time (end boundary). My Code looks quiet messed up and I am sure there should be an easier option. Should you have a Solution, please post.

Thanks Chris

Here my code that is handled in a loop

_in loop after no error from:   local request, err = client:receive()

```
if request:sub(1,4) == "POST" then
    print ("GOT DATA UPLOAD")

    request,err = client:receive()
    local state = 0
    local lastdummy = ""

    while state ~= 3 and not err do
            request,err = client:receive()

        -- data between bounderies
        if state == 2 then 
            if request == "\r" then print ("----OK"); end

            print (request)

        end

            if state == 0 and request:sub(1,13) == "Content-Type:" then
            a,b = string.find (request, "boundary=")
            if a > 0 then
                lastdummy = (string.sub(request,b+1))   
                state = 1
            end
        elseif state == 1 then
            if request == "--"..lastdummy then
                print ("startttt")
                state = 2
            end
        elseif state == 2 then
            if request == "--"..lastdummy then
                print ("ENNNNND")
                state = 3
            end     
        end

    end
    state = 0
    print ("done")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data is in [multipart/form-data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipart/form-data#Form_Data) format. You need to decode it. I suggest you to reuse some HTTP parsing library / code from any Lua HTTP server. (There are plenty, try googling them up.) For example: https://github.com/keplerproject/wsapi/blob/master/src/wsapi/request.lua

Also, check out this thread: http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2007-11/msg00178.html